# Login logout attendance checktime

Tags: mysql, authentication, logout

i have mysql data (table) from attendance program like this :

```
+--------+--------------------+-----------+
| userid | checktime          | checktype | 
+-----------------------------+-----------+
|      1 | 26/04/2013 8:05:17 | I         |
|      2 | 26/04/2013 8:05:17 | I         |
|      2 | 26/04/2013 17:28:47| O         |
|      3 | 26/04/2013 17:32:24| O         |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

and i want preview like this :

```
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
| userid | Login time         | Logout time         | 
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | 26/04/2013 8:05:17 | Null                |
|      2 | 26/04/2013 8:05:17 | 26/04/2013 17:28:47 |
|      3 | Null               | 26/04/2013 17:32:24 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

how should I write a query to preview this output?? any suggestions will be helpful for me.please help...

Comment: It should be assumed that only 2 same userid can be found, each with an `I` or an `O`, right?

Comment: How can user 3 logout without logging in first?

Comment: just like driver, where checkout in afternoon. sometimes people forgot to checkin (fingerprint program). time for checkin can be found in shift table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you provided this query should do it:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  max(if(checktype = 'I', checktime, NULL)) loginTime,
  max(if(checktype = 'O', checktime, NULL)) logoutTime
FROM t
GROUP BY userid
```

Output:

```
| USERID |          LOGINTIME |          LOGOUTTIME |
|--------|--------------------|---------------------|
|      1 | 26/04/2013 8:05:17 |              (null) |
|      2 | 26/04/2013 8:05:17 | 26/04/2013 17:28:47 |
|      3 |             (null) | 26/04/2013 17:32:24 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4e27/1).